# How to wrap an mmage map in <div></div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap

I am having some difficulty getting the .wrap and .wrapAll methods to work on my image map. I am assuming this is because `map` does not self close like an image or input tag.

```js
$.fn.setupV2 = function(map) {
  map_ref = "map[attribute='" + map + "']";
  img_ref = "img[usemap='\\#" + map + "']";
  $(map_ref).wrapAll('<div class="mapContainer"></div>');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img_class" id="bottle_map" src="../images/bottle.jpg" usemap="#bottle_map">
<map name="bottle_map">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="3,6,258,31" href="1" title="Saranac Legacy IPA">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="279,5,336,32" href="2" title="four generations">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="2,37,425,64" href="2" title="four generations">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="1,69,386,95" href="2" title="four generations">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="243,121,444,142" href="3" title="Matt Brewing Company">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="4,143,186,163" href="3" title="Matt Brewing Company">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="194,144,400,163" href="4" title="Our (great) grandfather">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="3,163,252,187" href="4" title="Our (great) grandfather">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="295,166,419,185" href="5" title="it's still family">
      <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="3,189,363,209" href="5" title="it's still family">
    </map>
```

I want to wrap the image and the image map into a div together so I can insert a canvas and CSS styling in. Is there a way to do this outside of injecting the HTML or having it done in the HTML to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to adjust your selectors so that jQuery grabs both the map, and the img.  Something like this would work:

```
$.fn.setupV2 = function(map) {
  map_ref = "map[name='"+ map+"']";  
  img_ref = "img[usemap='#" + map + "']";
  $(map_ref + ', ' + img_ref).wrapAll('<div class="mapContainer"></div>');
};
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/p0mLhecg/

> I am having some difficulty getting the .wrap and .wrapAll methods to work on my image map. I am assuming this is because map does not self close like an image or input tag.

Not exactly.  Your selector for `map_ref` and `img_ref` waren't matching any elements.  You'd need to update them so they match an the elements, and include both of them in the jQuery selector.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh wow that worked perfectly thanks! I had something extremely similar set up before with no luck. I must have been missing that comma which caused panic when it inevitably didn't work